# Bootswatch/flatly looks like standard bootstrap in server

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I have this ASP.NET MVC web application where I changed the standard Bootstrap.css (version 3.1.0) for the Bootswatch.css(flatly - version 3.2.0). I kept the original bootstrap.js file.

Well, when I run the app on my developing computer the styles (colors, sizes and so on) are accordingly with what I saw in the Bootswatch/flatly site, like the image bellow:

[image app on developing computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9fA9.png)

However, running the same app on the server the styles are more likely with the standard Bootstrap (colors, sizes and so on), like the following image:

[image app on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xzag.png)

In *Content folder* there are the following files:

- _bootstrap.css (original standard twitter-bootstrap.css file)
- bootstrap.css (bootswatch/flatly file)
- bootstrap.css.map (from original twitter-bootstrap)
- bootstrap.min.css (from original twitter-bootstrap)
- bootstrap-theme.css (from original twitter-bootstrap)
- bootstrap-theme.css.map (from original twitter-bootstrap)
- bootstrap-theme.min.css (from original twitter-bootstrap)
- bootswatch.min.css
- ... some other *css* files

So I ask how can I fix this. I'd like to have in server with the same look as in the developing computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking in other forums I got a [solution](http://forums.asp.net/p/2077387/5989922.aspx?p=True&t=635828388268185847).

I took bootstrap.css file (actually bootswatch/flatly css file) from css bundle and referenced it in _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an asset refresh/update problem

If in the server there are asset  check the one containing  your (old)  bootstrap and remone this  asset dir

Then at the new access you should see the new bootstrap flaty  in action

Or could be a server refreshing problem (for hosted) in this case some provider have configuration for development for make the change immediatly available and not cached.

Comment: Hi, @scaisEdge. I don't think it is the issue. I've ran the app many times and the result is always the same. Or I simply didn't understand what you meant. Thanks

Comment: Have you delete the asset related to bootstrap?

Comment: In fact when I first published the app on server it already had the bootswatch/flatly version for bootstrap. Thanks

Comment: In the server dir where are place the asset related to bootstrap

Comment: If you have already the flaty version.  In someway this is overwritten hit t a default bootstrap version..... (an update to new release???)

Comment: None of the cases. The same versions since app publishing. Thanks.